# Is there a way to delete Snowflake ODBC driver log file automatically or limit them?

Tags: odbc, driver, limit, logfile

I am currently using *Snowflake ODBC* driver and it creates a log file that gets bigger and bigger as time goes by.

Is there a way to limit the size of the log file? Or to make it overwrite itself? Instead of deleting it manually every time it is oversized?

Comment: Can you show us your current code/configuration/something that we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

If the OS is Linux you could make use of logrotation.

On Debian/Ubuntu
apt update &&
apt install logrotate

On CentOS/RHEL/Fedora
yum update
yum install logrotate

Answer (score 0):

You can also try turning down the "tracing" level ... it defaults to 4 (Info) to 3 or lower ... that might help contain the issue.